# Terminal command to get OSX notifications

Tags: python, macos, terminal, notifications

I am writing a script to record notifications on my Mac (OSX Yosemite). After some research I found a plethora of ways to post Mac notifications, for example the terminal command:

```
osascript -e 'display notification "Notification text" with title "Title"'
```

produces a simple notification. However I can't seem to find a way to access this notification after it has been created. Is there a terminal command to print out the notification?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way is to use sqlite to read the os database. How this is done specifically is a bigger question.

Comment: Were you ever able to figure it out?